# Shani Dev - Black or Blue?

Tags: rituals, shani

I have gone through various Puranas to know about the body complexion of Shani Dev. In Agni Puran, Skand Puran, Garud Puran (Agastya Samhita) - Shani Dev is mentioned to be of black color, black as a charcoal.
Only in Matsya Puran, he has been mentioned to be of dark blue complexion. Whereas every where else he is depicted black and the puja rituals to appease him also specifically make use of black articles (like black cloth, black sesame seeds, black gram, black bull, etc). SO why is Shani Dev more popularly seen as BLUE and not BLACK ? Any other important story/reference/context which I am missing ?
Also, what color clothes should a priest of Shani temple wear ?
Thanks in advance.